# Windows Command Line Nested Variables

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, set

I know I may not be using conventional programming here, but I'm so close to done with a batch file I want to use. It's dirty but it works. Just messed up on one thing, hopefully someone can help.

I will simplify the code. Say I have:

```
SET foldersize0=1000
SET foldersize1=2000
SET foldersize2=3000
SET foldersize3=4000
```

then I want to do an if/then:

```
IF %foldersize%rnd%% GTR %var% .... blah blah blah
```

How do I call the value of the foldersize based on the random number variable *rnd* so I can compare with another value? Obviously what I have posted doesn't work (*%foldersize%rnd%%*). Sorry for the newb question.

Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal 
SET foldersize0=1000
SET foldersize1=2000
SET foldersize2=3000
SET foldersize3=4000
set /a rnd=%random%%%4
call set "foldersize=%%foldersize%rnd%%%"
echo.%foldersize%
endlocal
```